# Cannot submit a form in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit

I am using jquery smarty, php. I am validating a form using jquery but the submit button is not working. 
In checkemail.php I am echoing no of rows;

```js
$(document).ready(function() { //newly added 
  $("#formpge").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailVal = $('#useremail').val();
    alert(emailVal);
    // assuming this is a input text field
    $.post("checkemail.php", {
      "useremail": emailVal
    }, function(data) {
      alert(data);
      if (data == 0) {
        alert("has to be added");
        $("#formpge")[0].submit();
      } else
        $("#useremail").focus();
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formpge" name="frmadduser" method="post">
  <div class="input1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Full Name" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="input2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="useremail" name="useremail">
    <p color="blue" id="emailexist"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="input1">
    <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="active">
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="iwant_text2">
    <input type="submit" id="formsubmit" name="formsubmit" value="I Want One!">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Any php errors if you change to $_GET and load it from location bar? Does the alert trigger?

Answer (score 0):

try this code its working: -

```
<form id="formpge" name="frmadduser" method="post">
  <div class="input1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Full Name" id="username" name="username">
  </div>
  <div class="input2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email Address" id="useremail" name="useremail">
    <p color="blue" id="emailexist"></p>
  </div>
       <div class="input1">
    <input type="hidden" value="Y" name="active">
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div class="iwant_text2">
    <input type="submit" id="formsubmit" name="formsubmit" value="I Want One!" >
  </div>
  </form>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 
$("#formpge").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var emailVal = $('#useremail').val();
alert(emailVal);
// assuming this is a input text field
 $.post("checkemail.php", {"useremail" : emailVal}, function(data) {
    alert(data);
    if(data == 0){
    alert("has to be added");
    $("#formpge")[0].submit();
    }
    else 
    $("#useremail").focus();
 });

});
});
  </script>
```

[try fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/prgsg4wL/)

Comment: How can you tell if it works, you have a php page you can test it against and see the requests going out? Because I don't think they will.

Comment: its working i am getting username in $_REQUEST variable in my php page.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to mplungjan, Gaurav Srivastava andStarscream1984. The problem is, in checkemail.php I checked isset($_REQUEST['formsubmit'], but this is not set only the text fields are set. I dont know why type submit is not set.
Again, Thanks.